# Adding to .data using javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, push

From all the answers I've been given, I've decided to use the object reference variable since I need .data to have the same name.  However I'm not sure if I am using the variable correctly.  I think I just need to do the following:

```
                      var myData = [];


                    $.ajax({
                            url: url,
                            dataType: "json",
                            cache: true,
                            success: function(data) {           
                            $.each(data, function(i, item){
                      myData.push(item);

                      });
                       alert(myData);
```

Unfortunately its still not working correctly..

when I call the function onload i get the following output from the alert 10,
" [object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]"

when I call the function a second time to get the next 10, I should have 20 objects in the file but instead I have only 10 "object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]"

### ORIGINAL POST BELOW

Good day,

I am trying to add to some results from an Ajax call.  Currently json gives me 10 items.  When I call my loading function again, I want another 10 but I want to add it to the .data object so I get 20, then when it loads again 30, etc.
Is this possible to do?

The first call gives me back 10 results.  It is:

```
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    dataType: "json",
    cache: true,
    success: function(data) {           

    }
});
```

I have set the following conditions for the second call.

```
if(data ===! null || data ===! 0 || data ===! ""){          
    $.each(data, function(i, item){
        data.push(item.text);
    });
```

The second call is not adding to data at all.  I'm not sure what I should do.  I have read from other questions that data is an object that holds an array.  Why can't I just push 10 more to the array?   Any help is appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: can you put the ajax reply here?

Comment: please post that to your question and not in the comment. also, we need the structure of the reply. is the reply an array or an object?

Comment: I reply is an object, it is a json link I get back..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create an object to store the data into. The `data` that you are fetching each time is not the same object, so that is why you aren't seeing the additions. What you may want to consider is having just a single function, and have it behave like this:

```
myData = [];

$.ajax({
    url: url,
    dataType: "json",
    cache: true,
    success: function(data) {           
        $.each(data, function(i, item) {
            myData.push(item.text);
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: thanks I never considered that I was not getting the same object.  I am modifying code that references "data" for everything.  Once I do create the array myData, how can I assign its contents to data?

Comment: Can I use myData.push(data); or myData.append(data)  ?

Comment: `.push()` quick and easy way you can add a new array item to the end of a Javascript array object. `.append()` is adding a new DOM object within the DOM structure in jQuery, which isn't what you want.

Comment: If you're trying to use `.push()` on an object, it won't work as it is not an array. Therefore, if you set the variable as an object (`myData = {};`), then you will get an error. You will need to set it as an array (`myData = [];`).

Additionally, as a note, your updated code may not work because you are using the same variable name `data` in various scopes. That will definitely cause you issues.

Comment: yes I noticed.  I am definitely having some issues with scopes now.  I have updated my code with my updates.  However I am still not getting .data to give me the extra 10 items.  Not sure what I am doing wrong...

Comment: I suspect that you have that full code within a function (either `$(document).ready()` or a `.bind("click")`. If that is the case, you are probably calling `myVar = [];` each time, which effectively resets your array time you execute your code. You should declare `myVar` outside of your function's scope (such as a global variable).

Comment: You were right.  myData is now collecting all the info for me.  Last question... how can I push myData into data?  Since so much of the other code depends on data, I need that to update.  I can't use push since its an object, so what can i use?

Comment: That would be starting to get into a whole other discussion itself, but in short, if `myData` must be an object, you can always create an array as a property of `myData`. I would recommend doing a bit more reading about Javascript objects and arrays.